# VB .net 2010 - Get Substring of String in quote

Tags: string, vb.net, substring

I have a file which contains some lines. I managed to find all lines in a Loop. The lines I need look like this: (PS: I thinnk there can be used regex for this..)

```
if "%testfile%"=="abcd" (
```

This file contains more of this lines but the abcd changes to whatever. Also there could be different blanks like

```
if  "%testfile%" =="abcd" (
```

etc.

I want to get

```
abcd
```

in a variable inside my Loop that I can use it further.

Following part is doing it: ( lineArray.Item(x) contains the whole line )

```
            For x = 0 To lineArray.Count - 1
              If lineArray.Item(x).Contains("%testfile%") Then
                MsgBox(lineArray.Item(x)) 'here should it be done.
              End If
            Next
```

Comment: If `abcd` will never contain double-quotes then you could split the string on `"` and take the fourth part.

Comment: Was the answer helpful to you? Feel free to [upvote & accept](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 2):

You are absolutely right, this can be done with a regex. I suggest this pattern:

```
(?<=if\s+"%testfile%"\s*==\s*)".*?"(?=\s+\()
```

[Online Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dif%5cs%2b%22%25testfile%25%22%5cs*%3d%3d%5cs*%29%22.*%3f%22%28%3f%3d%5cs%2b%5c%28%29&i=if++%22%25testfile%25%22+%3d%3d%22abcd%22+%28+%0d%0athis%29%0d%0aif++%22%25testfile%25%22+%3d%3d%22kgh%22+%28+%0d%0aand+that%29%0d%0a&o=m)

**Explanation**

- `(?<=if\s+"%testfile%"\s*==\s*)` lookbehind to asert line in question with extra `+` / optiona `*` whitespace `\s`
- `".*?"` layz match the target string
- `(?=\s+\()` lookahed as rear anchor

[Code Sample](https://ideone.com/pATxei):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Example
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim pattern As String = "(?<=if\s+""%testfile%""\s*==\s*)"".*""(?=\s+\()"
        Dim input As String = "if  ""%testfile%"" ==""abcd"" ( "
        Dim options As RegexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline

        For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options)
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```